# Remove Margin Left and Right of a table iText java

Tags: itext

I have a problem with the **fixed** margin on left and right of a table.

[image]

I want remove that margin and use all the sheet without margin or padding. How i can do ?

I've just tryed this but doesn't work for me:

```
cell.setPaddingLeft(0);
cell.setBorderWidthLeft(0);
cell.setLeft(0);
```

This works for me, but the borders of the cell , don't follow the text
(Look at the table in bottom)

```
cell.setPaddingLeft(-50);
```

This is a part of my code :

```
Font fontStandard = FontFactory.getFont("Arial", 8);
int w[] = { 50, 50 };
PdfPTable tableInner = new PdfPTable(5);
tableInner.setWidths(w);

cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("PADDING -50", fontStandard));
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
/******/
//cell.setPaddingLeft(0);
//cell.setBorderWidthLeft(0); 
//cell.setLeft(0); 
cell.setPaddingLeft(-50);
/******/
tableInner.addCell(cell);
document.add(tableInner);
```

This is what i want.
[image]

Comment: Have you *set the width percentage that the table will occupy in the page* using the `PdfPTable` method `setWidthPercentage`?

Comment: No, i can try that

Comment: Ok, I have tried, and it doesn't works. The margin is still there.. @mkl

Comment: You do not show how you create your document. Have you reduced the document margins accordingly?

Comment: "Have you reduced the document margins accordingly"

I dont know how to reduce the margin..

Comment: By default they are 36 pt, i.e. half an inch. You can explicitly choose them using the `Document(Rectangle pageSize, float marginLeft, float marginRight, float marginTop, float marginBottom)` constructor, and you can change them using the `Document.setMargins(float marginLeft, float marginRight, float marginTop, float marginBottom)` method.

Comment: It works only for the top margin, now it's nearly to the top of the document with a little margin of 1 px, but the left and right margins are still there.

Comment: Please share the current state of your PDF creation code. Decreasing the margins and at the same time setting the width percentage to 100 should do the job. Thus, there seems to be some other issue in your code we need to track down.

Comment: OK, now it works well. Sorry, i had a little bug on my code that makes me some problems. Thank you so much, if you post your comment as answer with setWidthPercentage and using the document i give you the **best answer**. @mkl

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default the table drawn by a `PdfPTable` object only fills 80% of the width of the page content area width. You can change this ratio using the `PdfPTable` method

```
/**
 * Sets the width percentage that the table will occupy in the page.
 *
 * @param widthPercentage the width percentage that the table will occupy in
 * the page
 */
public void setWidthPercentage(final float widthPercentage)
```

to avoid those extra margins.

Furthermore, a `PdfPTable` instance added to a `Document` respects the document margin values. To use (nearly) the whole page as page content area for a table to fill, you have to reduce the document margins to (nearly) 0 using the constructor with 5 arguments

```
/**
 * Constructs a new <CODE>Document</CODE>-object.
 *
 * @param pageSize the pageSize
 * @param marginLeft the margin on the left
 * @param marginRight the margin on the right
 * @param marginTop the margin on the top
 * @param marginBottom the margin on the bottom
 */
public Document(Rectangle pageSize, float marginLeft, float marginRight, float marginTop, float marginBottom)
```

or the setter

```
/**
 * Sets the margins.
 *
 * @param marginLeft the margin on the left
 * @param marginRight the margin on the right
 * @param marginTop the margin on the top
 * @param marginBottom the margin on the bottom
 * @return a <CODE>boolean</CODE>
 */
public boolean setMargins(float marginLeft, float marginRight, float marginTop, float marginBottom)
```